# Html block all but a div

Tags: html, css, adblock

On uBlock Origin, I want to block all but the div :

```
<div class="fig-article-body" itemprop="articleBody">
```

HTML code :

```
<body class="fig-tmpl-article" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="shell">
<div id="a18310" class="fig-ad-display">
<style>
<header id="fig-header" class="figh js-figh--has-reader js-figh-cookie" role="banner">
<script src="//a.f1g.fr/h/assets-components/header-footer/jquery.app-banner.js">
<script id="fig-header-script">
<div id="a18318" class="fig-ad-display" style="text-align:center;line-height:0;">
<div id="page">
<div class="fig-container fig-ad fig-ad-megabanner" llnhv90="" hidden="">
<div id="flash-actu" class="fig-container flash-actu">
<script>
<div class="fig-art fig-container">
<div class="fig-art__main-pub">
<div class="fig-art-col-left">
<nav class="fig-metas">
<article id="20161008ARTFIG00061" class="fig-article fig-article-has-no-source" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemprop="mainContentOfPage">
<div class="fig-main-col">
<div class="fig-article-header">
<div class="fig-main-media" itemscope="" itemprop="primaryImageOfPage" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
<div class="fig-micronav-wrapper">
<p class="fig-chapo" itemprop="about">
<div class="fig-article-body" itemprop="articleBody">
<p>
<p>
<p>
<div class="fig-embed">
</div>
</div>
</article>
<div class="fig-recommended">
</div>
<div class="fig-art-col-right" data-default-category="1">
</div>
<div class="fig-container fig-article-more">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="fig-footer-gly">
<footer id="fig-footer" class="figh figh-footer">
<script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://a.f1g.fr/assets-js/xtcoreSimpleTag.min.js?b8d2426d089ed0ab6cf65136eac0b625cecda264">
<noscript><img width="1" height="1" alt="" src="http://logc111.xiti.com/hit.xiti?sts=1&amp;stc={%22s2%22%3A%221%22%2C%22isChargeable%22%3A%220%22%2C%22isClosed%22%3A%220%22%2C%22xtac%22%3A%22%22%2C%22xtan%22%3A%22%22%2C%22tags%22%3A%22notre-dame-des-landes%7Cnantes%7Cnddl%22}" ></noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script>
<iframe style="height: 1px; width: 1px; border: 0px none; position: absolute; display: none ! important; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;" src="//cstatic.weborama.fr/iframe/customers/premium.html?idEditeur=1145&idSite=181" hidden="">
<div class="OUTBRAIN" data-src="http://www.lefigaro.fr/actualite-france/2016/10/08/01016-20161008ARTFIG00061-notre-dame-des-landes-un-bras-de-fer-vieux-de-quarante-ans.php" data-widget-id="TR_1" data-ob-template="lefigaro" llnhv90="" hidden=""></div>
<script id="abine_0.21071100624206107:0.07245986728690512" type="text/javascript" async="async" src="http://widgets.outbrain.com/outbrain.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<img src="//amplifypixel.outbrain.com/pixel?mid=00cfaacd3ce7d5bf46d5f6a20eb138626e" style="display: none ! important;" hidden="">
<script id="abine_0.7840435651298917:0.926472799115202" type="text/javascript" async="" src="//radar.cedexis.com/01-10036-radar10.min.js">
<script id="abine_0.19025242154548905:0.3863868636641318" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//static.chartbeat.com/js/chartbeat.js">
</body>
```

Comment: Uh...as in, you want to hide every element except for that one? Odd requirement...but `body *:not(.fig-article-body){ display:none }` comes to mind. And I guess something similar to exclude its children. (Please clarify your question with more details, or you won't be getting many useful answers.)

Comment: Html is hierarchical... if so if you hide anything but that div... you may end having it hidden anyway (because you hid its parent). So I've suggest to tag all possible 'invisible' objects with a class and then just apply `display:none` to those. Be sure to leave anything from your `fig-article-body` parent's hierarchy off of that

Comment: @Serlite : Sorry for my poor question. I am testing on the page [link](http://www.lefigaro.fr/actualite-france/2016/10/08/01016-20161008ARTFIG00061-notre-dame-des-landes-un-bras-de-fer-vieux-de-quarante-ans.php), I have supply the filter `www.lefigaro.fr*:not(.fig-article-body){ display:none }` but it is not working !?!